# Get center of geojson Continent/Country/State with leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, markers

Is there a way of finding a center for countries/continents which consist of more than one polygon object(ex. USA, Canada, which have an islands besides main land part)? I was trying to use leaflet's `Layer.getCenter()` or even `Layer.getBounds().getCenter()`, but those methods certainly don't work for this type of countries and return a "no-go" results.

Example can be seen by the following link (leaflet playground). Just scroll and click on US or Canada and see where `circleMarker` will appear. Then try clicking on smaller entities, like some islands on south of US, they shall place this marker precisely on center of'em:

http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/voyi/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leaflet can only calculate the center of the bounding box of a feature. With a bit of help from other libraries (such as [Turf.js](https://web.archive.org/web/20170205051733/http://turfjs.org:80/docs.html#centerofmass)) you can calculate the [*centroid*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid) of the polygon or (multipolygon).

In any case, you are getting confused because sometimes the centroid is not within the polygon (or multipolygon):

[image]
<sub>(source: [postgis.net](http://postgis.net/docs/images/st_centroid03.png))</sub>

(Figure 1. Centroid of a polygon as per [PostGIS's `ST_Centroid` documentation](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Centroid.html))

So I guess that what you really wanted to ask is:

> Given a polygon or multipolygon, how can I calculate a center (or center-like point) which is guaranteed to be within the polygon and looks visually in the center of it, in order to add symbolizers to that point with Leaflet?

And for that, the answer is ["pole of inaccessibility"](https://blog.mapbox.com/a-new-algorithm-for-finding-a-visual-center-of-a-polygon-7c77e6492fbc?gi=96d9046ba184) as implemented by [`polylabel`](https://github.com/mapbox/polylabel): «the most distant internal point from the polygon outline».

Comment: Thanks, that actually is a proper question I've wanted to ask, but lacked knowledge about centroids. Thanks a lot, and I'll try to get a good result based on info you've provided

Comment: `polylabel` helps with a polygons. And how about 'multiPolygons'? Like for USA country which has South parth of North America and Alaska part? Is it possible to do something in this case?

Comment: Calculate the area of each of the multipolygon's outer rings, then apply `polylabel` to the biggest one. And/or, submit a feature request to https://github.com/mapbox/polylabel/issues

Comment: Sorry for asking, but is it a simple Shoelace formula? Or should any corrections be applied? Can you point me towards a right direction? Maybe you have any links/info about this, as I've never had any experience related to this. But I definitely would like to know more.