# leaflet js centre popup issue (only on a few countries)

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Disclaimer: I'm new to Stackoverflow so if I'm not following protocols just let me know!

Over the last couple of days I've started to learn Leaflet JS, its really cool. I've put together an interactive map, following the tutorials, and its not to bad. However, I'm having an issue with centring the popups for a select few countries.

In the highlightFeature function I've stored the centre point using `centrePoint = e.target.getCenter();` This seems to work for all countries except Russia, China, Australia, Canada and the USA. If anyone can point me in the right direction and shed some light as to why this might be happening I would be very grateful.

You can find the project here http://codepen.io/CucumberCoolie/pen/yMyrWq?editors=0010

```
// highlight interaction on mouseover
function highlightFeature(e) {
var layer = e.target,
    popup = L.popup(),
    name = layer.feature.properties.name,
    centrePoint = e.target.getCenter();

layer.setStyle({
    weight: 1,
    color: '#666',
    fillColor: '#fff7bc',
    dashArray: '',
    fillOpacity: 0.7
});

if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
    layer.bringToFront();
}

countryName.textContent = name;

facts.update(layer.feature.properties);

  // Add popup on mouseover
popup.setLatLng(centrePoint)
    .setContent(name)
    .openOn(map);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the countries that you mention (you forgot UK, but there are also many other small countries for which this effect is not obvious) are made of several distinct polygons (i.e. multipolygon).

`L.Polygon.getCenter()` computes a rough centroid using [only 1 of these polygons](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/v1.0.3/src/layer/vector/Polygon.js#L57-L90). E.g. in the case of USA, it is one of the Hawaii islands.

A simple, but not error-free, workaround would be first to get the polygon (country) *bounds*, then to get the center of those bounds:

```
centrePoint = e.target.getBounds().getCenter();
```

It works for countries with several polygons that are close enough (e.g. Canada, China, Australia, UK) or for which the "main land" is much bigger than the other parts (e.g. USA).

Updated Pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dvPxqy?editors=0010

But it gives a totally off position for countries with many parts all over the world (e.g. France), or which are spread apart because of the antimeridian (e.g. Russia).

You could try to refine the polygon centroid computation, in particular taking into account the multipolygon case.

You might also be interested in that post: [Get center of geojson Continent/Country/State with leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42108975/get-center-of-geojson-continent-country-state-with-leaflet/42109812#42109812)

Comment: Thanks for response, thats really broadened my understanding. The post you linked to is very interesting. 

I guess I could write a function that uses your method to find the centre for only the countries that are causing the issue, although it wouldn't be elegant. 

I shall definitely research the Mapbox solution linked to in the post you linked to. 

Thanks again, very helpful!