# How to get centroid for a GeoJSON feature coordinates?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I have a simple object of GeoJSON data with features having looking like this:

```
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          -94.62979125976562,
          35.6382942199707
        ],
 ...
```

It's not a Leaflet polygon object, just an object with simple values, so I cannot run its methods like `.getBounds().getCenter()`.

How do I know centroid using standard Leaflet functionality?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42108975/get-center-of-geojson-continent-country-state-with-leaflet/42109812#42109812

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get center of geojson Continent/Country/State with leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42108975/get-center-of-geojson-continent-country-state-with-leaflet)

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to create the polygon from the "coordinates" in the given GeoJSON. You can use the library **rgdal** for this and get polygon as,

```
 polygons <- readOGR(data, "OGRGeoJSON", require_geomType="wkbPolygon")
```

This will create a Formal class SpatialPolygonsDataFrame.

To find centroid of this polygon use the library **rgeos**. It contains a function called gCentroid.

```
Centroid <- gCentroid(polygons, byid = TRUE)
```

This gives a Formal class SpatialPoints of the coordinates of the centroid.

To finally extract the latitude and longitude you can do the following,

```
centroid <- list(centroid)
lat <- centroid$x  
long <- centroid$y
```